# Why am I only getting one item from list

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to get shared letters from a string compared to a list of letters. I only return the last letter of l that shares with w .  I want all the shared letters instead.

```
def f(w,l):
    common = []
    for i in w:
        if in i in l:
            return common.append(i)
```

Comment: You shouldn't be returning any letters ... `common.append(i)` will always return `None` ...  Assuming you're not trying to keep duplicates, etc, you're better off using sets:  `set(w).intersection(l)` will do more or less what you want.

Comment: You might consider using [sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) for `w` and `l`, so that you can just use `w.intersection(l)`. Also, consider renaming the varible `l` to `L`, since it looks like the number 1 in some fonts. See [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid)

Answer (score 6):

As soon as `i` is in `l` your code `return`s, which immediately exits your function. instead do this:

```
def f(w,l):
    common = []
    for i in w:
        if i in l:
            common.append(i) # no return needed so it will collect all
    return common
```

Make sure you return `common` at the end your function so you get all the values stored in `common`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def f(w,l):
    common = []
    for i in w:
        if i in l:
            common.append(i)

    return common
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `.append` method of a list returns `None`.  You were returning from the function the first time you did `.append`, so you were always going to return `None` from the function.

I think that what you are really looking for is a list comprehension:

```
def f(w,l):
    return [i for i in w if i in l]
```

As others have pointed out, you might want to choose more descriptive variable names.